# Magento 2 MSI error "There are no source items with the in stock status"

Tags: magento2, msi, magento2.4.3.p1, msi-source

I am trying to enable the MSI module after being disabled for a lot of months. Now MSI related tables are empty and it is throwing the error "There are no source items with the in stock status". How can we get the data in the empty MSI tables.

The current Magento version is 2.4.3p1 EE. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

The source items would not be available for the sku in inventory_source_tem.

Are you getting on addto cart?

Comment: No While add to cart its throwing Error

Comment: Please assign stock to the product you are facing error